# Exception Settings while releasing the application

Tags: c#, .net

I will publish my application however i don't have any experience releasing a new product.

What i want to ask is, What do you suggest before release the application ?

For Example, In the exception settings, there is a 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' it should be checked or no ?

As I stated above, i have no experience with releasing the new application and I will never see the application crashes for the small things in code etc.

Please show me the path that i should follow, Open to all advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' is a setting of Visual Studio. These settings define Visual Studio handles runtime exception during execution INSIDE Visual Studio. So that setting can be very handy during debugging, because it will stop execution and show where the exception occurred.

This setting has nothing to do with the compilation process or the release process. If you release your assemblies in a production environment and you run it WITHOUT Visual Studio, it simply runs, or will crash by any non-caught exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, Any of the exception settings after publish is not important? If there is try catch error it just it shows the message and continue the working ? Also, sometimes i face with issues like 'nullreference' or 'object not set of instance of a object' etc. I wonder that those errors obstacles for publishing application or they are ok if not happens all the time ?

Comment: Of course these exceptions are an obstacle. Those exceptions are the result of bad programming. So, the exceptions are not the problem, they are the symptoms. The real problems is the other code which is bad: the decease. You should not suppress the exceptions, you should fix the cause.